# Passing a javascript variable in an html table to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass the variable fn to the function myFunc using a button. I am new to javascript is there anyway to do this. I am using a table with the first and last name inputed by the use.The response should be a greeting. This table will eventually contain more rows and is part of a bigger project.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function ajax_post(){
    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

    var table = $("#resulttable");

    table.append('<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>ADD</th></tr>');

    table.append('<tr><td>'+
        fn+'</td><td>'+
        ln+'</td><td><button onClick="myFunc(fn)">Add</button></td></tr>') 

 }

function myFunc(fname){
    var firstName= fname

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Hello" + firstName;

}   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Example</h2>
Your First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" /> 
<br /><br />
Your Last Name: <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" />
<br /><br />
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">

<br /><br />
<div id="status"></div>
<br /><br />
<table border = "1" id="resulttable">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way to do so would be this:

```
table.append('<tr><td>'+
      fn+'</td><td>'+
      ln+'</td><td><button onClick="myFunc(\"' + fn + '\")">Add</button></td></tr>')
```

Comment: Does jQuery turn that `table.append(...)` into `table.children('tbody').append(...).end()` ? If not, this will fail in some browsers.

Comment: Specifically the way the HTML is I would leave it the way it is. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/98Y28/1/

Comment: No. You don't understand. You don't need to put `<tbody>` in yourself. It is *assumed* to exist by the DOM. The issue is whether the browser will *understand* when you ask it to add a `<tr>` directly to the end of the `childNodes` list of the `table` element (and whether jQuery works around it!). That's normally invalid, but most browsers allow it (implicitly appending to the `childNodes` list of`<tbody>`). Your test shows nothing of value.

Comment: Ok, so I did a bit of cross browser testing on the matter. Both Firefox 20 and Chrome 28, will not add the row, if you specify the `tbody` but there is no actual `tbody` tag in the DOM. Internet Explorer 9 on the other had will add the row. All three browsers will add the row in both cases if you don't specify the `tbody` in your selector. My conclusion on the matter is, code your jQuery exactly against your DOM and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table will eventually include more rows, you could use a template approach:

[Working Fiddle for multiple rows](http://jsfiddle.net/QwT59/2/)

**upated input element**

```
<!-- Note the APP.ajax_post change -->
<input name="myBtn" type="submit" value="Submit Data" onClick="APP.ajax_post();">
```

**script**

```
$(document).load(function() {
    // Creates a global APP variable that encapsulates all of the logic
    window.APP = {

        // Setup a template for later use
        rowTemplate: $('<tr><td></td><td></td><td><button>Add</button></td></tr>'),

        ajax_post: function () {
            var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
            var ln = document.getElementById("last_name").value;

            var table = $("#resulttable");

            // Don't add a header if it already exists
            if(table.find('th').length == 0) {
                table.append('<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>ADD</th></tr>');
            }

            // Clone the template
            var row = APP.rowTemplate.clone();

            row.find('td:eq(0)').text(fn);
            row.find('td:eq(1)').text(ln);
            row.find('button').on('click', function() {
                APP.myFunc(fn);
            });

            row.appendTo(table);
        },

        myFunc: function (fname) {
            var firstName = fname

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Hello" + firstName;

        }
    }

});
```